# Unresolved reference: providesHttpAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, okhttp

When I tried to input providesHttpAdapter in HomePresenter for variable datasource from NetworkModule, there was no reference regarding that reference from file NetworkModule just because I changed object class NetworkModule to class. I need your thoughts of information regarding this.

HomePresenter.kt

```
import id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeDatasource
import id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeResponse
import id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.Networkmodule
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class HomePresenter(private val view: HomeView, datasource: HomeDatasource) {
    fun discoverMovie(){
        view.onShowLoading()

        val dataSource = Networkmodule.providesHttpAdapter().create(HomeDatasource::class.java)
        dataSource.discoverMovie().enqueue(object : Callback<HomeResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<HomeResponse>, response: Response<HomeResponse>){
            view.onHideLoading()
            view.onResponse((response.body()?.results ?: emptyList()) as List<Result<Any>>)
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<HomeResponse>, t:Throwable){
            view.onHideLoading()
            view.onFailure(t)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

NetworkModule.kt

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import id.kotlin.belajar.BuildConfig
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class Networkmodule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor{
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = when (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                true -> HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                false -> HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
            }
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            addInterceptor(interceptor)
        }.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHttpAdapter(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().apply {
            client(client)
            baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        }.build()
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post HomeDatasource class? Also, we should use @inject if we need to inject HttpAdapter into Presenter

Comment: import id.kotlin.belajar.BuildConfig
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface HomeDatasource {
    @GET("/3/discover/movie")
    fun discoverMovie(
        @Query("api_key")
        apiKey: String = BuildConfig.API_KEY
    ):Call<HomeResponse>
}